# Openlayers interpolating a raster source

Tags: raster, javascript, openlayers

I need to show a raster layer in OpenLayers keeping its pixels as they are, i.e without iterpolating them when zooming in.

I managed to do that with an ImageStatic source following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35877192/6185152

But when using a Raster Source, the image gets interpolated. Take for example the following code that lets you show the ImageStatic layer or a Raster layer by commenting/uncommenting them (available at http://jsfiddle.net/cnadia/vfajwdmr/):

```
var extent = ol.proj.transformExtent(
    [-5.6342, 50.3331, 1.6607, 53.0559], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

source_img = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
  url: 'https://i.imgur.com/1mDzkTJ.png',
  imageExtent: extent,
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

layer_img = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: source_img});

source_raster = new ol.source.Raster({
    sources: [layer_img],
  operationType: 'image',
  operation: function(pixels, data) {
    debugger;
    var pixel = pixels[0];
    return pixel;
  }
});

layer_raster = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: source_raster
    });

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
        //layer_raster
        layer_img
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent),
    zoom: 6
  })
});

map.on('precompose', function(evt) {
  evt.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  evt.context.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
});
```

what I get is:

Correct image using ImageStatic:
[image: Correct image using ImageStatic]

Incorrect (interpolated) Raster Source Layer:
[image: Incorrect (interpolated) Raster Source Layer]

I tried using the Raster Source both in 'pixel' or 'image' mode, and the result is the same.

In this example I'm "bypassing" the image (return value = input value), but I obviulsy need to modify the pixels and that is why I need the Raster Source.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution. Using a "dummy" layer as source for the raster layer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenLayers 6.4.0 you can use the `imageSmoothing` flag in the image source to disable the blur effect. Documentation for [ol/source/Image~ImageSource](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Image-ImageSource.html).